# Função do suspend no Firebird

Tags: sql, procedure, firebird

Qual a função do **suspend** numa **procedure** no Firebird?

Answer (score 2):

Ao que me parece, com uma pesquisa bem rápida no Google, o `suspend` suspende a execução de uma procedure que está trazendo uma tabela de resultados (result set) até que quem a está chamado peça para trazer o resto dos resultados.

Fontes:

> "Only for SELECT procedures which return tables: Waits for the client to request the next line. Returns the next line to the client."
>   http://www.destructor.de/firebird/storedproc.htm
>
> "O Comando SUSPEND informa a Stored Procedure para suspender a execução até que seja solicitado dados pelo cliente."
>   http://www.devmedia.com.br/while-e-for-no-firebird/16734

Answer (score 2):

Em uma stored procedure, a função do `suspend` é enviar uma linha de resultados atuais dos parâmetros de saída (`returns`). A cada `suspend`, uma nova linha é enviada como resultado.

Answer (score 1):

A função do `suspend` numa SP (*Stored Procedure*) é suspender o código naquela linha anterior ao `suspend` e imprimir na tela o resultado daquele código, basicamente o mesmo que dizer "imprima". Em uma alusão a programação básica (C++) seria o equivalente ao `printf`.